# Wann wird im Plural ein "n" am Ende eines Substantivs angehängt?

Tags: grammatical-number

Wenn der Artikel eines Substantivs, von dem der Plural gebildet wird, gleich lautet, wird i.d.R. ein "n" am Ende des Substantivs angehängt:

> "Der Kellner bringt uns die Gabeln." (= die Gabel (sg.) / die Gabeln (pl.))
>   "Der Verkäufer hat viele Gürtel." (=der Gürtel (sg.) / die Gürtel (pl.) => unterschiedliche Artikel, deshalb kein "n")

Aber was ist nun grammatikalisch der Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Sätzen:

> "Der Gemüsehändler hat viele asiatische Lebensmittel."
>    "Der
>   Gemüsehändler hat eine große Auswahl an asiatischen
>   Lebensmitteln."

Nach welcher Regel wird im 2. Satz das "n" angehängt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siehe die [Deklinationen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lebensmittel) des Wortes "das Lebensmittel".

```
Kasus       Singular            Plural
Nominativ   das Lebensmittel    die Lebensmittel
Genitiv     des Lebensmittels   der Lebensmittel
Dativ       dem Lebensmittel    den Lebensmitteln
Akkusativ   das Lebensmittel    die Lebensmittel
```

Im ersten Beispiel steht "das Lebensmittel" im Akkusativ, während es im zweiten im Dativ steht.